# How can i pass object_id to the template for (deleteing record) in Django

Tags: django-models, django-templates

I have this code

```
book_model_delete = {
    'model' : Book, 
    'post_delete_redirect': "/boo/list/", 
    "template_name" : "books/confirm_delete.html",
   }
```

`(r'^book/delete/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', create_update.delete_object, book_model_delete)`

The template i am using is

```
<form action="/book/delete/{{object_id}}/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    Are you sure you want to delete
    <p><input type="submit" value="yes" /></p>
    </form>
```

Now when i click on delete then this confirmation page comes but i don't know how to get the object_id passed in URL in this template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for `{{object.id}}`:

> **[django.views.generic.create_update.delete_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/?from=olddocs#django-views-generic-create-update-delete-object)**
>
> > ...
> >
> > Optional arguments:
> >
> > > ...
> > >
> > > **template_object_name**: Designates the
> > >       name of the template variable to use
> > >       in the template context. By default,
> > >       this is '**object**'.

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution is to declare a hidden field with the value of the object_id:

```
<input type=hidden name="your_object_id" value="{{object.id}}"/>
```

and get it via request.PST in your view